# Debugging Python Multiprocessing Wont Shutdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, multiprocessing

I am working on a rather complex python multiprocessing codebase. It is an IOT type problem where multiple processes need to be active simultaneously to receive data. There is no set kill flag / kill condition (time, jobs etc). Instead kill is accomplished by switching a flag referenced by all processes which interrupts their run loops.

The issue I am having is that I am nesting multiple packages and some are containing their own run loops which are not terminated and block the flag check for termination. Correcting this may require a restructuring of the code base.

What I am currently looking for is an external (outside of the program) way to see which processes are running and failing to shutdown. If the tool can also show why all the better. I am welcome to any bash tricks or other methods people know for debugging python multiprocessing.

Comment: Without having a minimal reproducible example, its hard to offer guidance. When I have issues with subprocesses that spawn subprocesses, I generally use [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process). Knowing the `.ppid()` and `.pid()` of hanging processes is very useful. The Process Management section [here](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) is slightly easier to follow imo.

Comment: This is the originating code base. I have modified it a fair bit but the basic process control is the same.

https://github.com/PamelaM/mptools

Comment: So `proc.pid` is a helpful little nugget to have print out as is `top -c -p $(pgrep -d',' -f python)`. I can see my two offending processes, yet their PIDs do not match any of the process that started up and declared their PIDs WTF.